# How to handle errors in Razor view engine?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

How to handle errors in Razor (i.e. Null Exception)other than (try/catch)?

I do not want to insert (try/catch) block in every razor block.

Example (The (Model.ListofEntity) or (Item.Values) may be null and an exception might occur):

```
<table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <div id="chkCheckAll" class="divCheckbox">
                </div>
            </th>

            @foreach (var column in Model.ListofEntity.Columns)
            {
                int t = Convert.ToInt32(" ");
                <th>
                    @column
                </th>
            }

        </tr>

        @foreach (CVMEntities.Item Item in Model.ListofEntity.Items)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id=@Item.ID class="divCheckbox">
                    </div>
                </td>
                @foreach (var Value in Item.Values)
                {
                    <td>
                        @Value
                    </td>
                }

            </tr>
        }

    </table>
```

Comment: I did not mean syntax errors. I meant when an exception happens!!

Comment: Have you tried using if statements?  For example: `@if (Model.ListofEntity != null) { ... }`

Comment: @RobertPurcell This will not help for other exceptions.